# SqlDateTime overflow then Sql column type is ... datetime2(7)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I maked a table with a column typed "datetime2(7)".
With SQL Server Management Studio, I can modify and save with a value between MinValue (**0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000**) and MaxValue (**9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999**) without problem.

In C#, I'm an error `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM` but all types (in my program and in table) allows DateTime.MinValue !

Have you an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `SqlDbType.DateTime2`? `SqlDateTime` is going to be limited to the boundaries of `datetime`, not `datetime2`.

Comment: Per the error message, somewhere in the process a conversion is happening to `SqlDateTime`, which corresponds to `DATETIME`, which cannot store these values. Instead a parameter should have been used with the type set to `SqlDbType.DateTime2`. To know how and why this happens, you'd need to add more detail to the question: what kind of ORM are you using (if any), how are you declaring and storing the value on the C# end, and what code are you using to send the value to the database?

Comment: @AaronBertrand : but, SQL type is datetime2 !

Comment: @JeroenMostert : I check this. Indeed, I use a generic class developed for my company for all queries.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : I see where is the problem. I use ```(SqlDataAdapter instance).SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, value)``` and DbType selected with my object is DateTime.

I see how I can correct this. Thanks :)

Comment: Relevant [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Always specify exact SQL types, and length/scale for parameters

Comment: *I use a generic class developed for my company for all queries* ... *I use .. AddWithValue* - i'd say your problems just got a lot bigger than you realize, if that use of AddWithValue is pervasive. May I recommend you switch to EF/Dapper?

Comment: @Charlieface : Indeed. I see to modify and depreciate all functions that use ```AddWithValues()```.
I bookmark and share your link :)